# Could gravitons just be low frequency photons?

Tags: gravity, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

James Clerk Maxwell determined that E-M waves propagate only at the speed of light, so considered that light may be an E-M wave.  This was later shown to be correct.

Given that gravity also propagates at the speed of light, why is this same consideration (that gravity is an E-M wave) not also considered?

Answer (score 5):

An E&M wave is a dipole wave where gravitational waves are quadrapoles.  They are remarkably different.

Also, from your question title, gravitons have spin 2 and photons have spin 1.

Answer (score 3):

As far as we can tell, electromagnetic waves don't care what a particle's mass is, they only care about it's electric charge and spin. Gravitons have to interact differently with heavy particles and light particles. Since electromagnetic waves are insensitive to the mass, they can't have anything to do with gravity.

Answer (score 2):

A different take on [Michael's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/281992/26076) is that there is a vector theory of gravitation called Gravitoelectromagnetism which is almost completely analogous to Maxwell's electromagnetism (even this would not imply that gravitons were photons, though, only that they are analogous through the relationships between Maxwell's theory and GEM).

GEM can indeed be used for accurate calculations in some, weak gravity, régimes.

However, some of the reasons why a vector theory of gravitation will not work are talked about at length in Chapter 7 of Misner, Thorne and Wheeler, "Gravitation". The reasons are many, ranging from experimental falsification to theoretical difficulties. The assertion that a rank 2 tensor theory is needed rather than a vector theory is roughly equivalent to [Michael's Answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/281992/26076).

Three of the reasons I like to ponder are:

1. If one accepts the Riemann curvature tensor $R$ as the fundamental descriptor of spacetime geometry and seeks a theory relating this object to source "matter", then there is no way to do this through a rank one tensor derived from the rank four $R$. At least, not without many of the wonderful intuitive results that make deep sense arising along the way; for example: by simple geometry (not physics) alone, the divergence of the Einstein tensor vanishes; this result is an expression of the geometric result that the boundary of a boundary of a closed manifold is always the empty set. If we assign this vanishing-divergence object to the stress energy tensor, we force local conservation of momentum energy to be a property of the field equations "for free";
2. There is no way to express local momentum energy conservation with a rank one tensor equation. Once we understand special relativity, and that conservation of momentum and energy are intertwined, frame dependent notions, one cannot express their conservation through a vector divergence and the rank 2 stress energy tensor is then needed to express these notions;
3. The fixing of the Einstein tensor fixes 16 components of the Riemann tensor. The remaining components define the Weyl tensor, but although the Weyl can be fixed on a hypersurface independently of the Einstein, its derivatives are defined by the Einstein's derivatives (through the Schouten tensor). This means that the Einstein field equation, together with boundary conditions on an appropriate hypersurface, completely defined the Riemann. There is no way to completely defined the Riemann in general through a rank 1 tensor equation alone.

Of course, the above is begging the question somewhat as I start my argument out assuming the all-importance of the Riemann, but, since this object is an extremely simple (in principle) and clear expression of geometry, I take this as an intuitively reasonable thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

Also, to add to why gravitational waves are not EM, at low freqs:

1) we know how and have generated EM waves at very low freqs, and have detected them with electromagnetic equipment. There was no gravitational effects.

2) we have detected gravitational waves with no electromagnetic detection equipment. They had gravitational effects.

3) the effects of the two are different, one interacts with charges and the other with any mass, even without charge.

4) the theory is straightforward for gravitational waves, we can calculate their generation and detection, their polarization (which is that for spin 2), and that they only get generated by quadrupole moments, not dipole moments like EM waves.

5)they travel at the speed of light because that is the speed at which any wave that is associated with a zero mass particle, in this case the graviton, has to propagate like that particle at the speed of light (caveat: we still have not detected individual gravitons not have a good quantum theory of gravity, but in a low energy approximation it'll have to correspond to General Relativity, and when the gravitational waves are not extremely strong the theory can be linearized and corresponds to a zero mass spin 2 particle).

6) General Relativity (which gives you gravitational waves) Is a (very huge) generalization of special relativity (SR), which says that zero mass particles travel at the speed of light. SR is consistent with Maxwell equations, but also with GR and any theory in physics with zero mass particles or force carriers. SR has been fully proven (to within the accuracy limits, like any accepted theory in physics).

7) there's probably more reasons like those covered by the other answers.